# How Did Azure Linux Agent Pick Up macos-10.14 Job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I run a self hosted agent (Linux) in a Docker container on my machine. In the `azure-pipelines.yml`, I specified

```
pool:
  name: Default
  vmImage: 'macos-10.14'
  demands:
    - npm
```

`Default` is my self hosted agent pool and the only agent in that pool is the Linux agent above. I would've thought the agent wouldn't pick that job up since the vmImage is different. To my surprise, the agent picked the job up and built it successfully. I wonder why is that? What does the `vmImage` property actually do? If you could point me to the documentation of this behavior, I'd be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pool) the `vmImage` is valid only in Microsoft Hosted Agents, so when you put it probably the yaml think you want this kind of agents. maybe it's a bug...

> ```
> pool:
>   name: string  # name of the pool to run this job in
>   demands: string | [ string ]  # see the following "Demands" topic
>   vmImage: string # name of the VM image you want to use; valid only in the Microsoft-hosted pool
> ```